# What is difference between cloud shell and SSH?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wanted to know the difference between cloud shell and SSH?
I think cloud shell provides you a temporary virtual machine? I want to know what is its exact use?
And I think SSH is used to interact with the VM selected? Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In very simpler terms,

`Cloud shell` is a **managed** bash like interface which allows the GCP user to interact with service endpoints without the need of end-user to worry about the compute instance hosting this bash interface.

`SSH` is a protocol just like FTP, HTTP which allows a secured exchange of packets between a source and target machine assuming the right set of ports and firewall exceptions have been enabled on both ends. Using `Cloud shell` you can `SSH` into remote hosts of choice assuming the condition stated above i.e. permissions and ports are resolved.

Comment: In addition I would also say that the Cloud Shell provides a temporary [Compute Engine virtual machine instance](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#virtual_machine_instance), and this will persists while the Cloud Shell session is active, and terminates after an hour of inactivity. Also, this Cloud Shell is unique for each user, and it not depends on the project that you are using.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more thing. SSH is used to interact with a particular VM that I create whereas, cloud shell is used to just interact with the gcp services. Like a console to interact with gcp service. Is that right?

Comment: SSH as a protocol is used to interact with any Linux hosts as long as the permissions are in order. Cloud shell is a great way to interact with GCP native services.